# differences between return and print in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone explain why we get different output using print and return?

For this code:

```
def string(txt):
    for char in txt:
        print(char)

string('Stack')
```

the output would be:

```
S
t
a
c
k
```

And for this code:

```
def string1(txt):
    for char in txt:
        return char

string1('Stack')
```

the output would be:

```
'S'
```

Comment: The second code block will return `'S'` but the will be *no* output.

Comment: @KlausD. true, depends if you're on the interperter though because that if you are, you will get an output of 'S'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions iterate through the characters of the `txt` parameter, but the first one, `string` uses the `return` statements, which breaks the iteration and returns the first character to the caller. This is why you see only the `S` of `Stack`

`print` on the other hand outputs all the characters in order to the [standard output](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/stdout.htm), and returns only after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 1):

when you use return the function stops and returns a value, so it breaks out of the loop

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you use return you would return the value and leave the function.

```
def string(txt):
    for char in txt:
        print(char)
        return

string('Stack')
```

This code would also only print an "S" as your example with return. Because return as the word say return to the position you called it.